# How to make a new tex command in org-mode-latex?

Tags: preview, org-mode, xetex

In a general tex-file, one can easily define a new command, for my case, let me take this as an example:

To put this code in header

```
\newcommand{\dd}{\,\mathrm{d}}
```

I can use the shorter command to make the longer command work; it's good to do this, I also can compile org-file into tex if this command is added in header. However the preview `C-c-x-l` fails to recognize `\dd` even if this new command have been defined in header.

I think we can add some code in org package to make this work, right? how can I do this? I want to make preview `C-c-xl` recognize `\dd` as `\mathrm{d}`.

### Update

Let me expound my question.

I hope we can amend or add some codes in `~/org path/lisp/org-latex.el` to make `preview` recognize `\dd` as `\,\matherm{d}` in every org-file.

The way @pmr posed works in each org-file which added that code by hand. I expect we can make this  as default and needn't to add such code every time.

Answer (score 14):

You need to add your `newcommands` to the header

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \newcommand{\dd}{\,\mathrm{d}}

* TestOrg
  $\dd  d$
```

then they are considered by preview.

Let this be the place where I rant: Don't do it. This will cage your documents inside LaTeX and you will never get them out again without some significant effort. No matter how much people tell you to use newcommand to define your won aliases: don't touch it.

Comment: wow~I am curious about that if you used such codes you posted above and what did emacs happen?

Comment: I have tried your code, it is useful. 
Thanks. However my purpose is to amend some codes in org setting-up to make every org-file can do this automatically. Is there any idea ?

Comment: @x7x7 Please state that in your question. To get a default configuration for every use [include](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html)

Comment: What is the alternative to not using `newcommand`? Maybe defining macros to type things you always repeat?

Comment: @ZoeRowa check this one: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41170/where-to-define-macros-for-org-mode-latex-preview